# nodejs server cannot export service

Tags: node.js, typeerror, node-modules

Im currently running a nodejs server. The situation is this, I have a services folder, inside the folder, there are many service.js files. In each service, I will export the service and its functions. 
eg.

```
var service = {};
service.fun1 = fun1;
service.fun2 = fun2; 
...
module.exports = service;
function fun1(params) { ... };
```

Now, I have to require one service from another. For example, whenever I need to use the user service from another service, I will do

```
var userService = require('services/user.service');
```

And then I can use it as

```
userService.fun1(params).then(function(data){ ... });
```

I have a coupon service that need to require the user service. In the coupon service I can require all other service, except for the user service. And I got this error

```
TypeError: userService.getById is not a function
```

So I try to console log the userService, it is {}, which means it is not exported somehow. But from other services , I can require user service in the same way and it works fine.

So I try to require other service in the coupon service and all are working. So only the user service in coupon service is giving the error.

This is making me crazy.

------update -------

The code the throws the error is from coupon_service.js:

```
var userService = require('services/user.service');

    function getAllCoupons(params) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        if (params.field1 && params.field2 && params.field3 && params.start_index && params.page_length) {
            userService.fun1(params.field2).then(function(data) {
                if (data.response1 == params.expected1 && helper.userIsAdmin(params.response1, data.validate)) {
                    deferred.resolve(getAll(params.field2, params.start_index, params.page_length, params.filter));
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(getCoupons(params));
                }
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(getCoupons(params));
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Some more code from both files would help.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue probably lies with the coupon service code. You may want to post the code that's actually throwing the error. Some thoughts that come to mind: Could the variable "userService" be overwritten directly or indirectly? Is the relative path to "userService" pointing to the same file?

Comment: the path should be correct, because I can require userService from other services in the same folder.

Comment: in fact, right after var userService = require('services/user.service') , i console log userService, it is {};

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both services are in the same `/services/` folder, you should just be able to do:

`var userService = require('./user.service');`

since the path for the imported service should be relative to the importing service.

Comment: I just tried this method, got the same typeerror message. I thought it could be cache issue, so i npm clear cache , but error still persist.